# Angular 2 - Use a different base view for all components under a directory

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I am building an app that users can log in to. When they're logged in, they'll be able to see a sidebar with all of the admin navigation. However, I need pages, such as, Login and Register that will not have a sidebar.
Another condition is that I want to keep the URLs clean, so, for instance, I don't want 'admin' in the URL for everything that needs the sidebar.

In this application, there will be a lot of routes, so, for maintainability, I have separated the routes into contexts using child routes, so they aren't all in the same file.
You can imagine the route structure to be something like the following:

- register/
- login/
- context1/

  - items
  - items/:id
  - things
  - things/:id
  - ...
- context2/

  - users
  - users/:id
  - ...

I would like my directory structure to mimic the URL structure as closely as possible.

The sidebar is the same for all contexts so that is its' own component with the directive `app-sidebar`. Every component beneath context1 and context2 (i.e. context1/ItemComponent) needs to have the sidebar.

I can think of a few theories on how to do this, but, as I'm new to Angular 2,  I can't seem to execute them.

I have tried using the `data` property in routes to hide/show the sidebar (Note: I have many more routes that require the sidebar, so it should show by default and hide if specified).
I have also tried to have all the contexts under a different directory 'admin' so they all use the same base html template but it doesn't seem to work quite like the base html template in the `AppComponent` where everything uses it and the active component is output through `router-outlet`.

Any and all help is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, only users who are logged in need the sidebar. If thats the case, you should be able to disable the sidebar with a simple `*ngIf="isLoggedIn()"`

Comment: I think that would work for the most part, but I need to leave scope for something like docs that only logged in users can see, but doesn't require a sidebar. I don't like the idea of the sidebar visibility relying on the login status, rather than a showSidebar status

Comment: Alright, so you could have a `Service`, which `subscribe`s to router-events and decide, if the activated `route` needs sidebar or not. The `Component` which contains the sidebar could then consume this `Service` and again use a "ngIf" like `*ngIf="sidebarService.isSidebarNeeded()"`

Comment: Hmmm...I much prefer that, I'll try to implement it now and get back to you with the results

Comment: Brilliant, that has worked! I created a SidebarService which watches for changes in a Router and the uses an instance of ActivatedRoute to get the data for that route to change a boolean in the SidebarService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `Service`, which `subscribe`s to the `Router` and decides, if the active `Route` needs a `Sidebar`.
In the `Component` where your `Sidebar` is located, you could simply consume this `Service` and use `*ngIf` to show/hide the `Sidebar`:

```
<app-sidebar *ngIf="sidebarService.isSidebarNeeded()"></app-sidebar>
```